# Pandas, group dataframe and normalize values in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with different groups identified by an ID, something like:

```
ID,X
aaa,3
aaa,5
aaa,4
bbb,50
bbb,54
bbb,52
```

I need to:

- calculate the mean of x in each group;
- divide each value of x by the mean of x for that specific group.

So, in my example above, the mean in the 'aaa' group is 4, while in 'bbb' it's 52.
I need to obtain a new dataframe with a third column, where in each row I have the original value of x divided by the group average:

```
ID,X,x/group_mean
aaa,3,3/4
aaa,5,5/4
aaa,4,4/4
bbb,50,50/52
bbb,54,54/52
bbb,52,52/52
```

I can group the dataframe and calcualte each group's mean by:

```
    df_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
    df_grouped = df_data.groupby('ID')
    for group_name, group_content in df_grouped:
        mean_x_group = group_content['x'].mean()
        print(f'mean = {mean_x_group}')
```

but how do I add the third column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [1874]: df['mean']  = df.groupby('ID').transform('mean')

In [1879]: df['newcol'] = df.X.div(df['mean'])

In [1880]: df
Out[1880]: 
    ID   X  mean    newcol
0  aaa   3     4  0.750000
1  aaa   5     4  1.250000
2  aaa   4     4  1.000000
3  bbb  50    52  0.961538
4  bbb  54    52  1.038462
5  bbb  52    52  1.000000
```

Comment: It is good to be reminded of `.tranform` in groupby. I have often just use `.agg` just to find a way to broadcast the mean to all rows. +Up for that.

Answer (score 1):

The idea being in a neat one-liner:

`df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.X/df.loc[df.ID==row.ID, 'X'].mean(), axis=1)`

Comment: This is not very neat though!!

Comment: It is neat in the sense that it is closer to the spoken language, so to say. "For each row take X and divide it by its mean". Regardless of the neatness or not, I think it's still good to put more approaches to the problem to inspire other ideas for other problems as well.

Comment: Sure I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

One liner code to do that

```py
# divide X with mean of X group by ID

df['group_mean'] = df.X / df.groupby('ID').transform('mean').X
```